# How to set a join-subclass to be always updated (even if only the ancestor changed) in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-update, joined-subclass

I have an update trigger on the joined-subclass in the database. It should run every time the data changed even if the changed fields are all in the ancestor class. But hibernate doesn't update the subclass. Is there a way to make it update it even if nothing changed there?

Comment: What do you mean by _update trigger_? A trigger directly in the database?

Comment: exactly, and i need to trigger it even when the base table changes